# issues with the marlin-devs repository

Tags: 14.04, apt, marlin

I'm trying to install marlin file manager on ubuntu 14.04.
I add the repository

```
add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
```

then when I 'apt-get update' i get this little gem:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/marlin-devs/marlin-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/marlin-devs/marlin-daily/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And after that I can't find the marlin package to install it:

```
apt-get install marlin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package marlin
```

It would also seem that after that apt-get updates I can't get autocomplete for any package in the terminal, say if I type:

```
apt-get install gimp[tab]
```

I don't get a list of the available packages.

The last issue goes away after i remove the repository, but I can't quite put my finger on why this is happening and how I could get marlin on this machine. I've been looking around for a tarball but all roads seem to take me to the repository.

Any input would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~marlin-devs/+archive/ubuntu/marlin-daily) doesn't have any packages for Trusty. In fact, the last upload was more than a year ago, with the last supported version being Saucy. The last (non-automated) commit to their [repositories](https://code.launchpad.net/marlin) was before the upload. Therefore, I would say the project is either abandoned or has shifted elsewhere.

Comment: yeah it seems they moved on to Pantheon File Manager